# angularjs counting object length

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I'm using underscore to count object length. `_.size(object)`. Because this object is being handled by angularjs there's a `$$hashKey` property in the object that's making the length 1 larger than it should be. What's the correct way to count object lengths in angularjs?

Answer (score 9):

Will this do? `_.size(_.omit(object, '$$hashKey'));`

**Updated**

`angular.copy()` strips `$$hashKey` out for you. So it seems a more Angular way would be `_.size(angular.copy(object));`.

Comment: Nice, angular.copy seems like the best solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

What about `_.size(angularObject) - 1;` ?

If this isn't enough, you can of course create your own size function that dosen't count the `$$hashKey`:

```
_.extend(_, { 
   mySize: function(collection, ignored) {
    var size = 0,

    _.each(collection, function(value, key) {
      if (!_.contains(ignored, key)) {
        size++;
      }
    });

    return size;
  } 
});
```

Example:

```
var len = _.mySize(angularObject, ['$$hashKey']);
```