# how to know the length of the object attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to know length of object.
for example:

```
var my_object = [{"id":1,"news":"test"},{"id":2,"news":"test2"}]
$scope.length=Object.keys(my_object).length;
```

in html i write the code with {{length}}, and the result is 1.

i want the actual result is 2, please help me to resolve the problem.

thank you

Comment: how about creating a plnkr.co or jsfiddler code sample for better debugging. `Object.keys(my_object).length; ` should be 2.

Comment: Check this topic. <br/>
[angularjs counting object length][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335108/angularjs-counting-object-length

Comment: I'm sorry, i get data from controller $http,
$scope.postings=myService.getData();
$scope.length=Object.keys($scope.postings).length;

when i write {{postings}} the result is [{"id":1,"news":"test"},{"id":2,"news":"test2"}],
and {{length}}  the result is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
$scope.length = my_object.length;
```